# 3d transformation in html5

Tags: 3d

I am trying to understand 3d-transformation in html5 and when it's rotation, scaling and moving - it is [simple](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543005/3d-transformation).
But adding perspective confuses me.
For example we have a rectangle: [400, 200], origin is in the center [200, 100], transform matrix is:

```
1   0       0       0
0   0.7     -0.707  -141.421
0   0.7     0.7071  -141.421
0   -0.001  -0.001  1.177777
```

And we have a point in the bottom-left corner [0, 200], considering origin: (0 - 200, 200 - 100) = (-200, 100).

Make transformation:

```
1   0       0       0           -200    -200
0   0.7     -0.707  -141.421    100     70  
0   0.7     0.7071  -141.421 x  0    =  70
0   -0.001  -0.001  1.177777    0       -0.1
```

If I throw 3d & 4th parameter I get (-200, 70), considering origin it's [0, 170]. I simulate this in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n43jl/gaahx/1/), and the point should be somewhere about [20, 32], considering origin it's (-180, -68).

So what is the math of 3d-transformation here? How webkit or other html-render gets the point (-180, -68) instead of the vector (-200, 70, 70, -0.1)?

Comment: Searching StackOverflow with terms "rotation translation matrix" will show you a number of related posts explaining the use of a matrix multiplication to represent both rotation and translation of points.

Comment: Thank you. «posts explaining the use of a matrix multiplication to represent both rotation and translation of points.» - rotation, scaling and translation causes no problems. Problems appeared after perspective, because I get z and perspective coordinates, and don't know what to do with them.